Micro Integrator dashboard problem while login
The issue is that I keep receiving the message, "No running micro integrator instances found. Please start a server and login." message.
I looked at everything; is there anyone who can advise me on how to handle this? Please find the deployment below.MI and MI dashboard deployment.toml file
This dashboard error https://i.sstatic.net/nSWiGMlP.png
MI Dashboard deployment.toml file https://i.sstatic.net/xF5K1Gni.png
Micro integrator  deployment.toml file https://i.sstatic.net/65jbVZkB.png

Please refer to the following WSO2 documentation: https://mi.docs.wso2.com/en/4.2.0/install-and-setup/install/running-the-mi-dashboard/.
You don't need to change any configuration in the MI Dashboard deployment.toml unless you require customization.
